# search a single word in a column

Tags: php, sql, database

[image: This is the column]

I want to fetch the one word out of the 4 words in the column category. For example I search for Buffet and the restaurant that has Buffet will display. This is my code so far and unfortunately it doesn't work.

## HomeController

```
public function searchresto(){

     $searchinfo = $_POST['searchinfo'];

     $this->load->model('RestoModel');
     $restaurantinfo['restaurantinfo']=$this->RestoModel>searchRestaurant($searchinfo);

     $this->load->view('pages/searchDisplay',$restaurantinfo);
}
```

## RestoModel

```
public function searchRestaurant($searchinfo){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE restoname = '$searchinfo' OR restocuisines = '$searchinfo' OR category = '$searchinfo'";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $result->result('array');

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: this is why you normalize the db, and not sore data like this

Comment: You could do `category like '%term%'`. You shouldn't pass user input directly to a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

First, sanitize user input. Never query the database directly from the user input, as this may cause [SQL Injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

After sanatizing the user input, try using the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) function.

For example:

`SELECT 'Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Buffet, Snack' LIKE '%Lunch%'` would output 1.

`SELECT 'Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Buffet, Snack' LIKE '%NonExistantCategory%'` would output 0.

---

Try changing your query to `SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE category LIKE '%$searchinfoSanatized%'`, where `$searchinfoSanatized` is the input that has been filtered/escaped.

Also, I believe you are forgetting a `-` after RestoModel: `$restaurantinfo['restaurantinfo']=$this->RestoModel>searchRestaurant($searchinfo);`

Comment: how do I sanitize the user input?

Comment: @Yuki a simple way is to use your DB class's escape function. Look at [this article on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)